How to get Complete value of Cookie in Excel using VB?
Sub GetCookie_Price()

    strUrl = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES%20IN%20F%26O"
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "REFERER", strUrl
        .SetRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7"
        .send

        response = .getAllResponseHeaders
        strCookie = Split(response, vbCrLf)
        fcookie = Trim(Split(Split(strCookie(5), ";")(0), ":")(1)) & "; " & Trim(Split(Split(strCookie(6), ";")(0), ":")(1))
    End With

    Sheets("Cookie_Price").Cells(5, 5).Value = fcookie

Exit Sub

here: MsgBox "Unable to reach Nifty, please connect to the Internet and try again.", vbCritical
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:04:00"), "GetCookie_Price"
End Sub
This code is giving a part of cookie value. that is

but I want complete value of cookie.


Have you checked the value of response before splitting this string?

its giving all information regading everything.

Excel worksheet cell has limitations to maximum characters it can contain and that may be causing this. Try saving the cookie in a text file.
